# Can not call View:make in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, constructor, composer-php, laravel-artisan

Can not call View:make function. Im getting this error:

```
 return View::make('fb-post.index',['users'=>$users]);

               Class 'App\Http\Controllers\View' not found
```

Route

```
  Route::get('/', 'PostController@test');
```

Controller

```
public function test()
{
  $customers = 'test';

  return View::make('fb-post.index')->with('customers', $customers);

}
```

My template file is in view/fb-post/index.blade.php

When im calling

```
 php artisan dump-autoload
```

getting:

```
        exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Command "dump-autoload" is not defined.' in /var/www/html/laravel-test/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:549
        Stack trace:
        #0 /var/www/html/laravel-test/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(192): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->find('dump-autoload')
        #1 /var/www/html/laravel-test/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(126): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
        #2 /var/www/html/laravel-test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(91): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
        #3 /var/www/html/laravel-test/artisan(36): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
        #4 {main}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you mean `composer dump-autoload` rather than `php artisan dump-autoload`? That's the `composer` command to rebuild the class autoloader mapping

Comment: @MarkBaker L4 artisan also has dump-autoload. And contrary to popular belief, it doesn't do the exact same thing. It also compiles classes in addition. So I don't know what to use now in L5...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `View` facade is not in the current namespace. So you either prepend it with `\`:

```
return \View::make('fb-post.index', ['users' => $users]);
```

Or add this at the top of your controller file:

```
use View;
```

Also, from the error you're getting, I assume you're using Laravel 5. In that case you can use the `view` helper function:

```
return view('fb-post.index', ['users' => $users]);
```